# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity

Tags: android

I nedd a little help! I'm trying login with facebook, but I'm getting this error and I cannot make it.

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity

        class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    }

    fun fbClicked(view: View) {

        facebookButton = findViewById<View>(R.id.facebookButton) as Button?

        // Initialize Facebook Login button
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

        facebookButton!!.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            facebookButton!!.setEnabled(false)

            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this@MainActivity, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"))
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSucess$loginResult")

                    handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.accessToken)

                }

                override fun onCancel() {

                }

                override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error)
                }
            })
        })

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        mCallbackManager!!.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }    

    private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(token: AccessToken) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:$token")

        val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.token)
        mAuth!!.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                        val user = mAuth!!.getCurrentUser()

                        val intent = Intent(this, InitActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)

                        facebookButton!!.setEnabled(false)

                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                        facebookButton!!.setEnabled(true)
                    }
                }
    }


}
```

So it's just this. Before I had managed to connect facebook with the app, but this time, I do not know why, it is giving this error of null pointer Exception.

And this is the error

> ```
> 09-23 12:33:23.139 8000-8000/com.juny.repartilhe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.juny.repartilhe, PID: 8000
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.juny.repartilhe/com.juny.repartilhe.MainActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4067)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4110)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
>  Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>     at com.juny.repartilhe.MainActivity$fbClicked$1$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.kt:74)
>     at com.juny.repartilhe.MainActivity$fbClicked$1$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.kt:71)
>     at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:659)
>     at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:245)
>     at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:174)
>     at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:92)
>     at com.juny.repartilhe.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:102)
>     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6549)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4063)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4110) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
> ```

Comment: I don't understand the `fbClicked()` function. It looks like it's meant to be called from XML, but then you use it to initialize and set a click listener on another button?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the entire Java stack trace, not just the error line. My guess is that `mCallbackManager` is `null`.

Comment: The `fbClicked()` is just the function when clicked fb button.